# Помогите исправить запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Есть скрипт загрузки изображений на сервер.

```
session_start(); 

include('bd.php');

include('uploadlib.php');

$MY_ID = $_SESSION['id'];
$poll_id = (int)$_SESSION['poll_id'];

echo $poll_id;

// Все загруженные файлы помещаются в эту папку
$uploaddir = '../images2/';

// Вытаскиваем необходимые данные
$file = $_POST['value'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

// Получаем расширение файла
$getMime = explode('.', $name);
$mime = end($getMime);

// Выделим данные
$data = explode(',', $file);

// Декодируем данные, закодированные алгоритмом MIME base64
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$data[1]);
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);

// Вы можете использовать данное имя файла, или создать произвольное имя.
// Мы будем создавать произвольное имя!
$randomName = substr_replace(sha1(microtime(true)), '', 12).'.'.$mime;


// Создаем изображение на сервере
if(file_put_contents($uploaddir.$randomName, $decodedData, $poll_id)) {

    // Записываем данные изображения в БД
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `images` (id, poll_id, date, catalog, filename) VALUES ('','$poll_id', NOW(),'$uploaddir','$randomName')");
    echo $randomName.":загружен успешно";
}
else {
    // Показать сообщение об ошибке, если что-то пойдет не так.
    echo "Что-то пошло не так. Убедитесь, что файл не поврежден!";
}
```

Проблема в том, что в последнем запросе не добавляется переменная `$poll_id`, вместо нее всегда добавляется 0. Но если принудительно указать например `$poll_id = 123`, то значение добавляется. Сама переменная хранится в сессии и через echo выводится корректно.

Comment: И если у вас id с AUTO_INCREMENT, то его в INSERT писать не обязательно)

Answer (score 1):

Если переменная числового типа выводится с помощью echo, а в поле базы данных добавляется 0, то возможно тип поля не совпадает с типом переменной $poll_id.

Answer (score 0):

Все решил проблему, ошибка была как всегда из-за невнимательности. Переменная некорректно сохранялась в сессию.